# More Terminals in Explorer right-click menu on Win11

Tags: cmd.exe, windows-11, windows-terminal

I have Window Terminal set to start WSL by default. I often want to open Terminal to a specific folder from Explorer. The problem is that since WSL is the default, it always opens a Linux shell, even if I'd actually need cmd.exe.

Is there a way to have both WSL & cmd.exe on the right-click menu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Almost": You get the option for Powershell and bash via **Shift**+RightClick by default. You can add/reenable the context menu "open to cmd" via registry change:

- open `regedit`
- goto `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\cmd`
- change ownership of the key to you (otherwise you won't be able to make the changes in the next step, make a note of the current owner, usually it's TrustedInstaller)
- give write access to your user (or to whatever group you want to use to do the change - otherwise you won't be able to make the changes in the next step, again, make a note of the original settings)
- change the value name `HideBasedOnVelocityiD` to `ShowBasedOnVelocityiD`

Shift+RightClick will now give you the option to `open command window here` (cmd.exe, not the terminal application).

[image]

I would recommend reverting the changes to the security settings afterward. To add the TrustedInstaller as an owner you need to type in `NT Service\TrustedInstaller`.

Comment: On Windows 11 you have to Shift-RightClick, then pick 'Show More Options', but 'Open command window here' is there. And Terminal can be set to be the default terminal for all apps, including cmd.exe, so it actually opens Terminal for me.